I get this ERROR Command "make:export" is not defined. Did you mean one of these?
First, I already have the maatwebsite/excel package installed when I want to do the following
$ php artisan make:export UserExport --model=User
I get an error:
ERROR Command "make:export" is not defined. Did you mean one of these?
⇂ make:cast
⇂ make:channel
⇂ make:command
⇂ make:component
⇂ make:controller
⇂ make:event
⇂ make:exception
⇂ make:factory
⇂ make:job
⇂ make:listener
⇂ make:livewire
⇂ make:mail
⇂ make:middleware
⇂ make:migration
⇂ make:model
⇂ make:notification
⇂ make:observer
⇂ make:policy
⇂ make:provider
⇂ make:request
⇂ make:resource
⇂ make:rule
⇂ make:scope
⇂ make:seeder
⇂ make:test
⇂ make:view
I already tried removing the package and reinstalling it, so far nothing has worked
I also tried to reinstall the packages and nothing

Is the package being installed successfully? And what version of Laravel are you using?

@EyadBereh
I was already able to solve the problem, it was another package that conflicted with maatwebsite/excel, in the end I only had to specify the version of both packages so that they affect each other:
"maatwebsite/excel": "3.1.48",
"phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.18",

needs some experts to format the text and code
